# Dúvida com formato json asp.net core web api

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, json

Olá

Tenho um exemplo funcional de consulta de dados buscando o cep, os dados são retornando no formato:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
    function searchCep () {

        // Recupera o value do input cep
        let cep = document.getElementById('cep').value

        // Inicia requisição AJAX com o axios
        axios.get(`http://api.postmon.com.br/v1/cep/${cep}`)
                .then(response => {
                                                console.log(response.data)
                    showResults (response.data)
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    // console.log(error)

                    // Mostra a div com o erro
                    document.getElementById('error').style.display = 'block'

                    // Mostra a mensagem
                    document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = 'Erro inesperado'
                })
                .finally(() => endPreloader ())

        event.preventDefault()
    }


function showResults(registros) {
    console.log(registros)
    console.log(`<p><b>Estado: </b> ${registros.nome} </p>`)

    // Mostra a div com o resultado
    document.getElementById('results').style.display = 'block'

    // Mostra os resultados:
    document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = `
                <p><b>ID: </b> ${dados.id} </p>
                <p><b>Nome: </b> ${dados.nome} </p>
                <p><b>Sexo: </b> ${dados.sexo} </p>
                <p><b>Estado: </b> ${dados.estado} </p>
            `
}
```

Este modelo funciona, mais se eu tenho dados em outro formato, não consigo captura as informações, apesar delas retornarem;

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Se está retornando um array de objetos, é só fazer um loop e dentro dele colocar a função showresults()

Comment: @EvertonNeri, o problema e que no formato ele vem [{"id:"3}] como ele está vindo com [], então não estou conseguindo pegar o conteúdo

Comment: o primeiro print é retornado um objecto "{}", já no segundo é retornado uma array "[]" de objetos "{}", que seria algo assim: "[{},{},{} ...]"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para captura os dados de um  array, eu posso utilizar:
console.log(registros[0].nome)

o exemplo final ficaria assim:

```
    // Mostra os resultados:
    document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = `
                        <p><b>ID: </b> ${registros[0].id} </p>
                        <p><b>nome: </b> ${registros[0].nome} </p>
                        <p><b>idade: </b> ${registros[0].idade} </p>
                        <p><b>sexo: </b> ${registros[0].sexo} </p>
                        <p><b>Estado: </b> ${registros[0].estado} </p>
                    `
```